# Как равномерно распределить элементы в GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, grid-layout

Размещаю в GridLayout 4 кнопки, но из за размеров текста ячейки не равны по размеру. Это видно по картинке снизу, где ячейки справа шире.

У всех кнопок одинаковые значения атрибутов:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/add_word_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="add word"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/RedButton"
        app:cornerRadius="@dimen/rounding" />
```

[image: Как выглядит экран]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layout_width="match_parent"    
layout_weight = "1"
```

есть такая вещь как `weight` или `"вес"`. относитесь к ней как к пропорциональному значению. так же у `Layout'ов`, в которых такие элементы хранятся есть `weightsum`.

поиграйтесь с этими значениями и посмотрите результаты.
единственное важное замечание! параметр `ширины` **ИЛИ** `высоты` должен быть у таких элементов `match_parent` или `0dp`

Comment: Вес он у меня уже был поставлен. А вот изменение ширины на 0dp помогло. Спасибо